# OPTION( Recompile) на запросе ускоряет его

Tags: sql-server

Допустим, есть запрос, который использует в себе объявленные переменные ранее в коде.

Примерный запрос:

```
SELECT * FROM Table1
where rec_id IN (SELECT Rec_id FROM Table2 where Type=@Type)
```

Rec_id- это PK.

Так вот, без `OPTION( Recompile)` он рисует один план выполнения запросов, где используется `HASH JOIN`, а с ним используются вложенные циклы и параллельные операции.

В первом случае запрос выполняется 40 сек и имеет такую статистику:

> Scan count 3, logical reads 10512025, physical reads 5667, read-ahead
>   reads 332036, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob
>   read-ahead reads 0.

Во втором случае моментально и с такой статистикой:

> Scan count 3132, logical reads 20050, physical reads 0, read-ahead
>   reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead
>   reads 0.

И выполнение тормозит не подзапрос(он выполняется моментально), а результирующая выборка.

Я PK дефрагментировал, кеши планов сбрасывал и статистику обновлял, но он все равно не меняет плана запроса без указания OPTION( Recompile).

Это так называемое сканирование переменных?

Comment: Запрос является частью хранимой процедуры, или это ad-hoc с объявлением переменной выше в батче? Что по поводу статистики по полю Type, какое распределение значений?

Comment: @DenisRubashkin ad-hoc

Answer (score 4):

1. Первый запрос выполнялся на "холодном" кэше, о чем говорит наличие физических и опережающих чтений. Второй и последующие вызовы того же ( без `OPTION( Recompile)` ) запроса выполнятся быстрее.
2. О влиянии `OPTION(Recompile)` и параметров на ad-hoc запрос.

Создадим песочницу для теста

```
CREATE TABLE #Table1 (
    rec_id  INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    Info    VARCHAR(200)
);

CREATE TABLE #Table2 (
    rec_id  INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    Type    INT,
    INDEX ITable2_Type NONCLUSTERED(Type)
);

INSERT #Table1 (Info)
SELECT TOP (1000) name
FROM master..spt_values;

INSERT #Table2 (Type)
SELECT TOP(10) 0
FROM #Table1
UNION ALL
SELECT 1
FROM #Table1
CROSS JOIN (VALUES (1), (2), (3), (4), (5), (6), (7)) N(Num);

ALTER INDEX ITable2_Type ON #Table2 REBUILD;

DBCC SHOW_STATISTICS ('tempdb..#Table2', ITable2_Type);
```

Итого у нас 1000 строк в таблице #Table1 и 7010 строк в таблице #Table2 с таким распределением:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Выполняем в той же сессии:

```
DECLARE @Type INT;
SELECT @Type = 0;

SELECT * FROM #Table1
where rec_id IN (SELECT Rec_id FROM #Table2 where Type = @Type);

SELECT * FROM #Table1
where rec_id IN (SELECT Rec_id FROM #Table2 where Type = @Type)
OPTION(RECOMPILE);
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Часть XML для первого запроса:

```xml
<SeekPredicates>
  <SeekPredicateNew>
    <SeekKeys>
      <Prefix ScanType="EQ">
        <RangeColumns>
          <ColumnReference Database="[tempdb]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[#Table2]" Column="Type" />
        </RangeColumns>
        <RangeExpressions>
          <ScalarOperator ScalarString="[@Type]">
            <Identifier>
              <ColumnReference Column="@Type" />
            </Identifier>
          </ScalarOperator>
        </RangeExpressions>
      </Prefix>
    </SeekKeys>
  </SeekPredicateNew>
</SeekPredicates>

<ParameterList>
  <ColumnReference Column="@Type" ParameterDataType="int" ParameterRuntimeValue="(0)" />
</ParameterList>
```

Для второго:

```xml
<SeekPredicates>
  <SeekPredicateNew>
    <SeekKeys>
      <Prefix ScanType="EQ">
        <RangeColumns>
          <ColumnReference Database="[tempdb]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[#Table2]" Column="Type" />
        </RangeColumns>
        <RangeExpressions>
          <ScalarOperator ScalarString="(0)">
            <Const ConstValue="(0)" />
          </ScalarOperator>
        </RangeExpressions>
      </Prefix>
    </SeekKeys>
  </SeekPredicateNew>
</SeekPredicates>
```

Какие выводы из приведенной выше информации

- Первый запрос на момент компиляции не имеет информации о значении
  переменной @Type - в плане запроса для этой переменной есть только
  ParameterRuntimeValue, поэтому количество строк он оценивает по
  Density Vector и получает 7010*0,5 = 3505. Соответственно в плане мы
  видим соединение таблиц посредством Merge join.
- Во втором запросе переменная @Type заменена на ее конкретное
  значение, оптимизатор может использовать гистограмму и сделать точную
  оценку количества строк, и для такого количества выбран оператор Loop
  join.

По сути дела первый запрос выполняется в режиме `(OPTIMIZE FOR UNKNOWN)`

Comment: А как высчитывается All Destiny? Это селективность индекса, да?

Comment: И как бороться с подобными косяками? Только хинтами? Вроде, всегда все говорят, что MS SQL Server'у виднее, как лучше выбирать данные.

Comment: Destiny = 1/Количество уникальных значений (в данном случае 2). Этот косяк решается помещением запроса в процедуру, но тогда включается parameter sniffing со своими косяками.

Comment: А динамические запросы будут работать таким же образом, как вы описали в ответе или, как процедуры?

Comment: Динамические через вызов `sp_executesql` будут работать как процедурный вызов

Answer (score 3):

Описанный вами эффект называется **parameter sniffing** (прослучивание переменных).

SQL Server кэширует план запроса, созданный при первом запуске запроса / хранимой процедуры, с любыми значениями параметров, которые были использованы во время этого первого запуска.

Варианты решения проблемы:

Использование хинта `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` является хорошим решением, когда ваши запросы не выполняются часто или не остаются в кэше запросов большую часть времени в любом случае.

Хинт `OPTION (OPTIMIZE FOR (@Type UNKNOWN))` или `OPTION (OPTIMIZE FOR (@Type='Type'))` лучше использовать, когда можно указать значение, которое позволит генерировать план запроса, который эффективен для большинства значений параметров и в порядке с получением хита для неоптимального плана на нечасто запрашиваемых значениях.

Существует также вариант использования логики (например, `IF/ELSE`) что даст вам максимальную гибкость и производительность, но будет не лучшим решением для долгосрочного обслуживания.

*В случае если данные распределены равномерно, а кэшированные планы оптимальны для всех значиний переменной, такой эффект наблюдаться не будет.*

Comment: Это не parameter sniffing, он применим для процедур, но не ad-hoc запросов. Здесь проблема в том, что без рекомпайла запрос вообще ничего не знает о значении переменной.

Comment: @DenisRubashkin, а зачем он тогда хеш джойн пытается использовать? Ведь этот же метод соединения, на мой взгляд, хорош, когда точно все известно.

Comment: @DenisRubashkin вы не правы, прекрасно проявляется на ad-hoc запросах, приходящих с аплекух например. Все у чего есть переменная и  кэшированный план, потенциально может подвергнуться проблеме.

Comment: Я пишу ответ, там все будет понятно.

Comment: Запросы, "приходящие с аплекух" выполняются посредством вызова процедуры sp_executesql, поэтому не являются "чистыми" ad-hoc. Разница в том, что в плане ad-hoc запроса не бывает ParameterCompiledValue.